# convert the for loop to lambda expressions in c#

Tags: c#, .net

How should I write using Lambda functions and make this to just one/two lines?

```
 public static SaaSWorkflowMatrix? GetPrevNode(this IList<SaaSWorkflowMatrix> coordinates, string username)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (coordinates[i].UserName == username)
                        return coordinates[i - 1];  // Need error checking
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }

           
        }
```

I tried this

```
return coordinates[coordinates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == username).currentIndex -1];
```

but it didnot work

Comment: When `coordinates[0].UserName == username`, then `coordinates[i - 1]` will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` - are you sure about the logic?

Comment: Can you understand the original code you wrote? Do you think a reader maintaining that code (a year from now) will understand it. Once you get your eventual code working, do you think you or that maintenance programmer will be able to understand it better (sorry  but it's obvious that you don't understand it now). Do you think your lamba-based code will run faster (or slower) that the base code - and if so, will the change be noticeable? Nice readable code beats convoluted single lines of code nearly every time (btw, I've done a lot of maintenance programming over the decades)

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `FindIndex` method

```
var index = coordinates.FindIndex(p => p.UserName == username);
```

then if index is -1, not exist in the list something with `UserName == username`

Answer (score 1):

`Reverse` allows to iterate backwards, then the prev become the next.

`SkipWhile` allows to iterate until the element searched.

`Skip` allows to iterate to the next element (precedent if enumeration is reversed).

```cs
coordinates.Reverse().SkipWhile(u => u.UserName != username).Skip(1).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var result = coordinates.FindIndex(i=> i.UserName == username) > 0 ? coordinates[coordinates.FindIndex(i=> i.UserName == username) - 1] : null;
```